# Use float counter in a section title

Tags: floats, captions, counters

I defined a new float environment for examples

```
\usepackage{float
\newfloat{example}{htp}{example}
\floatname{example}{Example}
```

that I the use throughout the document

```
\begin{example}
...
\caption{yet another example}
\end{example}
```

with automatic numbering and a table of examples

```
\listof{example}{List of Examples}
```

Now I have some long examples that I wish not to put in a float but give as subsections:

```
\subsection*{A long example}
...
```

How can I make this subsection to get included in the numbering of examples (with title "Example X: A long example") and appear in the list of examples?

---

**P.S.:** Claudio Fiandrino has provided a boilerplate which I adopted for my document the following way (looks like the solution depends on you document style, I use `scrbook`):

```
\newcommand{\subsectionexample}[1]{
  \stepcounter{example}
  \subsection*{Example \theexample: #1}
  \addcontentsline{example}{example}{\protect\numberline{\theexample}#1}
}

\subsectionexample{A long example}
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe,lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{example}{htp}{example}
\floatname{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
\listof{example}{List of Examples}

\begin{example}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{another example}
\end{example}

\subsection{A long example}
\stepcounter{example} %advance the counter of the example float
\addcontentsline{example}{subsection}{\theexample \hskip.66cm A long example} %add to the list of examples
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{yet another example}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had to slightly modify the solution, as included in my question.

Comment: The number in the lists is usually formatted using `\numberline`. Then `\theexample \hskip.66cm A long example` becomes `\protect\numberline{\theexample}A long example` without magic number (`.66cm`).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I wasn't aware of this, thus my merely attempt using `.66cm`. Thanks! `:)`